# How to get additional product information in cart.php in opencart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am using opencart for a web project and I add a custom field to all products called `unit`. I created a column named `unit` in the `oc_product` table. I can access a product's unit on the product.php page by adding `data['unit'] = product_info['unit']` and fetching it via a query, but I want to access it on the cart.php page. I am not sure where the cart get's its products from thought. So I don't know where exactly to add the code to get the unit. In `controller/common/cart.php` there is this block of code:

```
      $data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id'=> $product['product_id'],
            'key'       => $product['key'],
            'thumb'     => $image,
            //THIS
            'unit'      => $product['unit'],
            'name'      => $product['name'],
            'model'     => $product['model'],
            'option'    => $option_data,
            'recurring' => ($product['recurring'] ? $product['recurring']['name'] : ''),
            'quantity'  => $product['quantity'],
            'price'     => $price,
            'total'     => $total,
            'href'      => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
      );
```

If you look at the code above, right blow the comment THIS, I added a line to get the unit. Adding that code doesn't give me the unit and I know it doesn't because I am not querying it but I don't know where to add the query. If I replace $product['unit'] with a simple string like "12", I can access the 12 on the cart page. So the question is which query do I edit to get the unit on the cart page?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Go to line `242` int `/system/library/cart.php` and in the array add the following line

```
'unit'  => $product_query->row['unit']
```